# How to apply div opacity only on background image and not on text inside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a simple css3 animation, and apply opacity to the background image when the text jumps but it effect the whole div's.

[image: Image info - how it should look]

[Here is the jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qk6ufpr0/2/)

And this is the main wrapper div:

```
.movie_thumb_wrapper {
    float: left;
    line-height: 31px;
    background-color: #424755;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 140px;
    width: 220px;
    background-size: 220px 140px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-color:#1a1c26;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach from [Vitorino Fernandes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29119735/3436942) would be to 'nest' a pseudo element between the text and background:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:white;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
div:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /*this changes on hover - you might just want to change it here to get rid of the hover altogether*/
  z-index: -1;
}
div:after {
  z-index: -2;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
div:hover:before{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }
```

```html
<div>Hover to see effect</div>
```

---

So, in terms of your fiddle, add:

```
.movie_thumb_wrapper{
  position:relative;
}
.movie_thumb_wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition:all 0.8s;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:-2;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qk6ufpr0/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am not sure how to apply it on my code, may i ask you to try explain to me maybe on the jsfiddle link?

Comment: @alonblack: I've just noticed that you're using prefixing for border-radius. Nowadays, that's not really needed jsyk.

Comment: @jsbutler483 Can you please explain to me why the position:relative is necassary?what does it do to it?

Comment: when you position absolutely, it positioned to the next available parent with position relative or position:absolute. Here our parent has been set to relative. @alonblack

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you can't. you need to create layers, using CSS position absolute, and z-index, so the text sits "on top of" the semi transparent layer. (instead of "inside" it as a a child element)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pseudo` element `:after`

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .7;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1; /* so that it goes in the backward */
  background: url('http://placeimg.com/200/480/any')
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Check my background image</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: much better approach :)

Comment: have made a slightly different answer based on this approach - but if you wanted to edit mine in, i'll delete

Answer (score 0):

instead of hex color code specify rgba and adjust a as required

```
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

[reference](http://www.css3.info/opacity_rgba_and_compromise/%20reference)

Answer (score 0):

Uhm,

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

does the job!